# Using tmux copy mode just like vim

Tags: vim, tmux, copy

I'm trying make use of the copy mode of tmux to copy some part of text in one of my panes but I cannot really manage with it, spacebar is not working to select the text and I'm getting a bit lost.

Does somebody know how to set tmux to behave similary to vim? (moving with h,j,k,l , yanking with y , Visual Mode kind of selecting....)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `mode-keys` to `vi` (the default is `emacs`):

```
set -g mode-keys vi
```

You should put this in `.tmux.conf` and either restart tmux entirely (`tmux kill-server`) or also run it from the command prompt (`C-b :`).